# Why is Apache serving a new certificate and an expired one?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

*Due to the fact that this is a sensitive client project, all uses of the domain name I'm talking about have been replaced with "example.com".*

I am managing a public website whose Let's Encrypt certificate expired recently. So I followed the DigitalOcean tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) and used `certbot-auto renew` to renew the certificate (yes, I ran `sudo service apache2 reload` afterwards). It worked, but the problem is that the site now serves both the new certificate and the expired one, and it seems like a random selection happens. Sometimes the site is trusted by the browser because it receives the new one, other times the browser rejects the expired certificate. Even running the site through the [SSL Labs analyzer](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) gives an A grade sometimes and a failure other times.

What could possibly be causing both certificates to continue to be used when my configuration explicitly includes only the new one? I'm very confused.

Running `certbot-auto renew` right now gives this result:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cert not yet due for renewal

The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
No renewals were attempted
```

Apache's sites-enabled directory looks like this:

```
000-default.conf  000-default-le-ssl.conf
```

And the configuration for each are as follows:

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by calling `sudo service apache2 stop` to stop apache, and then running `ps aux | grep apache`. I discovered that there were multiple instances of apache running. So I killed them and started apache up again, and everything is now working.

Comment: And you do this every 3 months or is there a better solution?